# Jquery div is moved the the browser still thinks the mouse is over

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a website for my brother (those are not his pictures, they are random ones):
http://dev.denisduvauchelle.com/eric/2012/

**And I have an issue when I move the div in a jquery animation to the top of the page, and the browser still thinks the cursor is above the div making another animation, which is shouldn't.**

Here are the steps to re-create it:
1. Load the page
2. Click the logo
3. Move the mouse just a little bit
  ----> You'll see the menu drop downs and back up really quickly

That animation is suppose to happen once the user mouse hovers the white box around the logo.
So I'm guessing the browser still thinks that the mouse is over the box and making the animation, what kind of solution can I find for this?

Thanks and please let me know if I am not clear.

Here is the code for when the user clicks the logo:

```
    $('#logo').live('click',function(){ 
        var attr = $(this).attr('title'); 
        if(attr === "Enter"){ 
            stop_fullscreen_flicker();
            $('#header_first').fadeOut(speedNormal);
            $("header").delay(500).animate({
                "top" : spacing_header+'px'
            }, 'slow').css("backgroundColor","#FFF");
            $(this).attr('title','');
            $("#header_work").delay(1000).slideToggle('fast', function(){
                // Load the first project
                var first_loaded_project = $('#first_loaded_project').val();
                $('#link_'+first_loaded_project).addClass('external');
                $('#link_'+first_loaded_project).trigger('click');
            });
        } else {
            set_href('about');
            $("#content").fadeOut('fast',function(){
                $("#header_work ul").slideUp('fast');
                $('#backstretch').hide();
                $("#about").fadeIn('fast');
                $("#about").addClass('on');
                set_href('about');
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

and here is the code for mouse over :

```
    $('#header_work h1').live('mouseenter',function(){
        $("#header_work ul").slideDown('fast');
    });

    $('header').live('mouseenter',function(){
        $('#header_work h1').addClass('h1active');
        var attr = $('#logo').attr('title'); 
        if(attr !== "Enter"){ 
            $("#header_work ul").slideDown('fast');
            var img_src = "a_img/take-a-chance.jpg";
            $('#backstretch').hide();
            $.backstretch(img_src);
            $('#content').hide();
            $('#backstretch').show();
        }
    });
```

Here is a jsfiddle for you to try out thanks to Sheikh Heera:
http://jsfiddle.net/kRs7Q/10/

Comment: Post your code for hover function.

Comment: @SheikhHeera - I attached the code. Thanks for letting me know if it helps.

Comment: Doubt it's relevant, but `.live()` is deprecated and you're supposed to use `.on()` now.

Answer (score 1):

[Does this help](http://jsfiddle.net/kRs7Q/4/) ?

```
$('header').on('hover', function(){
    $("#header_work ul").slideToggle('fast');
},function(){
    $("#header_work ul").slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't help.  Thanks though, any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try this http://jsfiddle.net/kRs7Q/4/ and remove $('#header_work h1').mouseenter(function(){...});

Comment: I really appreciate the effort. I tried what you have in the jsfiddle, and I updated the code code a bit to get more the same issue that I have: http://jsfiddle.net/kRs7Q/10/  . As you can see after you click on the logo area, and then move a bit your cursor, the drop down slides up. That shouldn't happen.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kRs7Q/11/, please me know if you are having any trouble with it. It's may be not appropriate but it is working now.